# lexer regular expression pygments g-code

Tags: python, regex, pygments

I'm trying to create a very simple lexer on Pygments
http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/
so that I might gain some experience with Python while doing something useful, and then proceed to create a more complex one. The lexer is for g-code, and I was able to:

- highlight comments of lines (but not block comments);
- highlight M and G commands (but not the other commands X, Y, Z, etc.

Here goes the gcodelexer.py

```
from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer
from pygments.token import *

__all__ = ['gcodeLexer']

class gcodeLexer(RegexLexer):
    name = 'g-code'
    aliases = ['gcode']
    filenames = ['*.gcode']

    tokens = {
        'root': [
            (r' .*\n', Text),
            (r';.*$', Comment),
            (r'^[gmtGMT]\d{1,4}\s',Name.Builtin), # M or G commands
            (r'[^gGmM][+-]?\d*[.]?\d+', Keyword), # other commands
            # (r'\+.*\n', Generic.Inserted),
            # (r'-.*\n', Generic.Deleted),
            # (r'@.*\n', Generic.Subheading),
            # (r'Index.*\n', Generic.Heading),
            # (r'=.*\n', Generic.Heading),
            (r'.*\n', Text),
        ]
    }
```

Basically the "other commands" only finds the first out of two or three per line and I don't see why... Also I tried to find a description of each token (keyword, name, operator, etc. but without success). Should their names be self explanatory perhaps?

Thanks

Update: current version

```
from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer
from pygments.token import *

__all__ = ['gcodeLexer']

class gcodeLexer(RegexLexer):
    name = 'g-code'
    aliases = ['gcode']
    filenames = ['*.gcode']

    tokens = {
        'root': [
            (r'^;.*$', Comment),
            (r'\s;.*', Comment.Multiline, 'blockcomment'),
            (r'^[gmtGMT]\d{1,4}\s',Name.Builtin), # M or G commands
            (r'[^gGmM][+-]?\d*[.]?\d+', Keyword),
            (r'\s', Text.Whitespace),
            (r'.*\n', Text),
        ],
        'blockcomment': [
            (r'.*;.*$', Comment.Multiline, '#pop'),
            (r'^.*\n', Comment.Multiline),
            (r'.', Comment.Multiline),
        ]
    }
```

[IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/2h4j7lw.png[/IMG]

```
M190 S50.000000
M109 S250.000000
;Sliced at: Sun 03-07-2016 17:55:50
;Basic settings: Layer height: 0.3 Walls: 1.2 Fill: 20
;Print time: 1 hour 9 minutes
;Filament used: 2.584m 20.0g
;Filament cost: 0.37
;M190 S50 ;Uncomment to add your own bed temperature line
;M109 S250 ;Uncomment to add your own temperature line
G21        ;metric values
G90        ;absolute positioning
M82        ;set extruder to absolute mode
G28 X0 Y0  ;move X/Y to min endstops
G0 X100 Y100
G28 Z0     ;move Z to min endstops
G29
G1 Z15.0 F100 ;move the platform down 15mm
G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
G1 F200 E3              ;extrude 3mm of feed stock
G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
G1 F10800
;Put printing message on LCD screen
;?IF_EXT0?M109 T0 S?TEMP0?
M117 Printing...

;Layer count: 19
;LAYER:0
M107
G0 F10800 X48.217 Y22.131 Z0.300
;TYPE:SKIRT
G1 F1800 X48.687 Y21.229 E0.01913
G1 X48.936 Y20.744 E0.02939
G1 X49.723 Y19.693 E0.05409
G1 X50.013 Y19.303 E0.06323
G1 X51.064 Y18.293 E0.09065
G1 X51.455 Y17.957 E0.10034
```

Comment: I actually just wrote a regex statement that parses gcode, it'll handle all G and M codes as well as X,Y,Z,I,J,K and F codes. Here's the regex statement I used:

   `(G|M|X|Y|Z|I|J|K|F)(?<val>-?\d*\.?\d+\.?)`

You can check the first group for whether it's G or M, then the second group will give you specific code.

If you can post some example gcode I'll see if I can edit it to work for you also.

Comment: Thanks Xander,
I think however that there are alot of extra codes (from A to Z)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code#Letter_addresses although less frequent than the ones you used. The problem I had was the first text regex. I will had my current version. Do you suggest any amendments? DIfferent tokens perhaps? Thanks

Comment: `[^GMgm0-9](?:-?\d*\.?\d+\.?)` should be what you're looking for as far as detecting non G and M code commands. Tot detect any commands you can use `([A-z])(?<val>-?\d*\.?\d+\.?)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who needs a gcode lexer here it is with the help of @Xander. If you want to contribute to its improvement here is the official github [repository](https://github.com/averter/lexers_pygments)

```
from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer
from pygments.token import *

__all__ = ['gcodeLexer']

class gcodeLexer(RegexLexer):
    name = 'g-code'
    aliases = ['gcode']
    filenames = ['*.gcode']

    tokens = {
        'root': [
            (r'^;.*$', Comment),
            (r'\s;.*', Comment.Multiline, 'blockcomment'),
            (r'^[gmtGMT]\d{1,4}\s',Name.Builtin), # M or G commands
            (r'[^gGmM][+-]?\d*[.]?\d+', Keyword),
            (r'\s', Text.Whitespace),
            (r'.*\n', Text),
        ],
        'blockcomment': [
            (r'.*;.*$', Comment.Multiline, '#pop'),
            (r'^.*\n', Comment.Multiline),
            (r'.', Comment.Multiline),
        ]
    }
```